# Prevent a dropdown ul to reappear on mouseenter while fading it out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Basically what I have is a dropdown menu, when I click on the `#default li` a dropdown `ul` appears containing two list items. The idea is that when you move your mouse out of the dropdown `ul` or when you click on a `.sub-option`, the dropdown `ul` will `fadeOut`. This works, however, if I click on a `.sub-option` and the dropdown `ul` starts to fade, and then hover over the `ul` before the `fadeOut` is done, it will stop fading and the `ul` will reappear.. How do I prevent this from happening? I want nothing to happen when you move your mouse over the `ul` when it's fading out.

I tried adding a `mouseenter` event that checks if the `ul` is being animated but I'm not sure what exactly to put inside of this function, a simple `return` did not work. Any ideas on how to alter my code below so that it behaves properly?

The dropdown:

```
<ul id="sort-options">
    <li id="default"><span>A-Ö</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub-options">A-Ö</li>
            <li class="sub-options">Ö-A</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The script that toggles the dropdown:

```
    $('#default').on('click', function() {

        $('#default ul').stop().fadeToggle();
    });

    $('#default').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#default ul').stop().fadeOut();
    });

    $('#default').on('mouseenter', function() {

        if ($('#default ul').is(':animated')) {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rageve/9/edit)***

```
$('#default').on('click', function(e) {
  $('ul', this).stop().fadeToggle();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('ul', this).fadeOut(); /* don't use .stop() */
});
```

the above works cause the `.stop()` used on the `click` event will stop any ongoing animations (the mouseleave `fadeOut()` which happens once the elements start to fadeToggle) and win! :)

---

**Otherwise** you need to stop the click bubble up the DOM tree and use:

***[jsBin demo using event.stopPropagation](http://jsbin.com/rageve/10/edit)***

```
$('#default').on('click', function() {
  $('ul', this).stop().fadeToggle();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('ul', this).stop().fadeOut(); // use .stop() but the issue will appear
});

$('#default li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();  // so dont let #default register any inner LI clicks
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. The jquery documentation of stopPropagation is a bit unclear I would say, could you explain exactly what it does?

Comment: Very useful notes, now I fully understand it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz wuups, I've realized how off was my answer actually yes, you can do it targeting the inner LI elements and assigning TO THEM! that the click should stop the propagation. But in the above case, the click will propagate in any case, it's just about the way we use `.stop()`. Edited. Sorry for complicating.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Added all the needed stuff to my answer. Happy coding